# Page Viewer web part is prompting show all content message

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, web-part

I recently added a page viewer web part on one of my site pages, to obviously display another web page. There were issues at first. Whenever I would go to that site page, a show all content message would pop up at the bottom of my browser. I would need to click this pop up message before the page viewer would show. Otherwise the site page would be blank where the page viewer was. I fixed this by going into my internet options security and enabling Displayed Mixed Content. Now I'm worried every new user I add to the site will have the same issue but not know how to get around it. What can I do about this?

Comment: You're probably showing http (insecure) content in an https (secure)  site. That is normal behavior.

Comment: So it's something I'll have to live with?

Comment: Not really. But this isn't a server side change. You have the option to disable this in IE. So the change is mainly from client side. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2625928

Comment: I hear you. I had hopes.